# Solaris command to make noise

Tags: unix, bash, solaris

I would like to do something like this:

```
myCommand;  commandToMakeNoise
```

myCommand runs for variable amounts of time and I would like to go and work on something else until it is done, but I would like to be told (probably with sound but I am open to other ideas) when the command has finished.

I am using Solaris with gnome.  So I am using different workspaces.  (Why visual queues probably will not work.  I also don't want to move that terminal from the workspace that it is currently in).

Also I don't want to use a terminal beep.  That comes out of my tower, I would prefer something that comes out of my headphones so as not to annoy my co-workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/bin/audioplay /usr/demo/SOUND/sounds/bark.au`

Answer (score 2):

Solaris has an [`audioplay`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9at/index.html) command.

Comment: Do you know where solaris keeps it sound files?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's easy to compile on Solaris w/ Gnome, but I use NotifyOSD on Ubuntu and the "notify-send" command.  Works well, unobtrusive and meshes with the environment.

Comment: +1: good suggestion, but does not ship with solaris.

Answer (score 1):

Simply throw random data to /dev/audio, something like:

`myCommand ; dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/audio count=100000`

Answer (score 0):

This will beep the remote console on the server.

```
echo -ne '\007' > /dev/console
```

I use it too, often, since the server is in the other room, and I like to have audio feedback when some key tasks are completed without looking at a console.